# Passing parameters through VBA to a parameter query joined in another query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have made a new query using an existing parameter query that is linked/joined to a table that will filter the line items from the list of activities.
How can I pass the parameter through VBA to parameters of related parameter query as there are no parameters defined on this query and I get 'Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected #' error for not assigning missing parameters.

I can get the parameters to work on the main parameter query itself but not on this new query where I am using it to filter out the table.

[image]

I have tried passing parameters as I would to the original query but still get the same error.

```
        Set boqQD = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryCvlExportRevRelatedBOQ")
        boqQD.Parameters.Refresh
        boqQD.Parameters("paramYear").Value = Me.cmbSearchYear
        
        Set rsBOQ = boqQD.OpenRecordset
```

Comment: Pass the parameter values to the _new_ query; it will pass them on.

Comment: @Gustav, isn't that what the posted code is attempting?

Comment: @June7: Yes, missed that. Then there will be more than one parameter.

Comment: @Gustav.  Could you advice on the approach please.

Comment: I did a test. Posted code should work if all parameters are passed a value.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for testing, Yes it worked fine after I added missing parameters. Given code is fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct. You can list the parameters like this:

```vb
Dim P As DAO.Parameter

Set boqQD = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryCvlExportRevRelatedBOQ")
For Each P In boqQD.Parameters
    Debug.Print P.Name, P.Type
Next
boqQD.Close
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav. Yes, the code indeed was correct but there were missing parameters from my side.